# Select * from tbl where id>=5 /* then add the result from id<5 to query */

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with 9 rows.

$id=5
If i use `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id>=$id` i get the 5,6,7,8,9 rows. To this query I want to add the result of `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id<$id` so I will get the final 5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4 rows.

This is to avoid going two times in database then add the result set in php.

EDIT: Yes order is important. Thank you guys for the fast response. Thank you @knittl(Accepted answer) and @Swanand for the best answers.

Comment: Is it the order you are looking for?

Comment: so, id>=$id or id<$id. that's every row …

Comment: @knittl - If `id` can contain nulls then it's not.

Comment: @martin: um, correct. missed that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you want all rows? if the order is what you are looking for, sort your result set:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
ORDER BY id >= $id DESC, id ASC
```

Comment: Does this work in MySQL? Just tried with this: `order by id >= @id, id`, doesn't seem to. I am sure I am missing something.
EDIT: I see, the `DESC` did the trick. +1 from me.

Comment: it does, i just tested. is @id set? try using a literal value

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
SELECT *, (IF(id<5, true,false)) AS ltfive
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ltfive, id
```

Comment: you are missing the FROM part

Comment: @knittle - oh yes. I'll fix that (not that it was a relevant part of the answer)

Answer (score -1):

[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) is your friend!

```
(SELECT *,1 as q FROM tbl WHERE id>=$id)
UNION
(SELECT *,2 as q FROM tbl WHERE id<$id)
ORDER BY q, id;
```

Comment: quoting mysql docs: »However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows.«

Comment: @knittl you're right. I didn't care too much about the order of results as the questions didn't say anything about it (the mentioned queries don't guarantee any order). I've now updated my answer to fulfill this additional requirement. For this very simple case, your answer still is more efficient though. In more complex scenarios, the constant (`q`) might come in handy (my hard-rocking amigo) though.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$id=5;
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id>=$id
union
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id<$id ;
```

Comment: Well... yes but this is exactly the same as... SELECT * FROM tbl

Comment: @Gimly - Not exactly. It is the same as `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id is not null`

Comment: Or to take my pedantry one step further it is actually the same as `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tbl WHERE id is not null`